# Error: request for member 'Name' in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, pointers, struct, member, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to write a program that will read data from a text file(**data2.txt**) into a dynamic array. and then print that data out onto the screen. When I run my program I am getting the error shown below:

```
Error: request for member 'Name' in something not a structure or union.
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error since I have included a header file in my program that includes a structure. The size of the array P is the first integer number in the file. Any help\guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the content of the text file **data2.txt**:

---

```
5
Martin Smith     22 2.2
Austin Clinton   18 3.1
Johnson          19 2.9
Maggie Jones     23 2.3
Tyler W Brown    16 3.4
```

---

here is the content of the header file:

---

```
typedef struct RECORD
{
char Name[15];
int Age;
float Gpa;

};
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Mo.h"

int main()
{

int n;
int number = 0;
int i=0;


FILE * fpointer;
    fpointer = fopen("data2.txt", "r");

    fscanf(fpointer,"%d",&number);
    n = number;

    printf("Size value is: %d \n", n);

   int *P = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

**[ERROR Showing on next line]**

```
  fscanf(fpointer,"%s %d %f", P[i].Name , &P[i].Age, &P[i].Gpa);

   while(! feof(fpointer))
   {
    printf("%s %d %.1f\n",P[i].Name , P[i].Age, P[i].Gpa);
     fscanf(fpointer, "%s %d %f",P[i].Name , &P[i].Age, &P[i].Gpa);

     i++;
   }



free(P);


fclose(fpointer);

printf("\n\n");
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you want your dynamically allocated array to hold records, you should declare `struct RECORD *p = malloc(n * sizeof(*p));`. At the moment, you have an arrays of `int`s.

Comment: Also note that the `%s` format will scan single words only. You will read in the first name, but fail reading the numbers, because the next input in the stream is the last name.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions as to what I can do to read in the last name?

Comment: My first suggestion would be not to use `fscanf`, because it treats spaces, tabs and newlines the same. If you have line-based input, it is better to use `fgets` first to read a line and then maybe read into that with `sscanf`. If you use any of the `*scanf` functions, make sure to check the return value, which is the number of items converted.

Comment: It is not quite clear what the exact format is. You could take the first 14 characters as name, for example and then use `sscanf` into the line from there. You could also look for two consecutive spaces and use that as delimiter between name and grades. In any case, you will have to implement a custom function.

Comment: You could also use `sscanf` on a line with a character range. For example, you could treat everything as name until you find the first numeric digit. Something like `sscanf(linebuffer, "%[^0-9] %d %f", P[i].Name , &P[i].Age, &P[i].Gpa)` could work, but I haven't tested it. (For this, your `Name` buffer will have to be bigger than 15 chars. 15 chars is very little anyway, "Austin Clinton" barely fits.)

Comment: Did Gopi's answer help you with your original problam? If so, please accept it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try implementing a custom function along with one of your suggestions and hopefully see were I get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int *P = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

Here `P` is a pointer of type `int` what you need is

```
struct RECORD *p = malloc(n * sizeof(struct RECORD));
```

`p` should be a pointer of type `struct RECORD`